# Issue retrieving AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'ndim' while plotting a 3d graph

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a 3d wireframe plot from a csv file. Data in format first column x is CPU in percentage (range from 10-90%), second column y memory (range from 10-80%), in percentage and last column drop rate in percentage(range from 10-70%).
Sample data

```
10,10,30
10,20,10
10,30,5
10,40,30
20,10,4
20,20,30
20,30,40
20,40,20
sample_data = np.genfromtxt("data.csv", delimiter=",", names=["x", "y","z"])
x, y, z = zip(*sample_data)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.set_xlabel('CPU')
ax.set_ylabel('Memory')
ax.set_zlabel('Rate')
ax.plot_wireframe(x,y,z, color='green')
plt.show()
```

I am retrieving below error

```
   if Z.ndim != 2:
   AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'ndim'
```

Comment: Full traceback, please.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are expecting too much from `zip`.  `zip` is a Python function that generates tuples from iterables.  Python tuples are not numpy data structures and therefore cannot respond to an ndim request.  If you want to acccess the data points associated with `x`, `y`, and `z` as ndarrays then you want to do something like the example below:

```
from io import StringIO
import numpy as np

txt = """10,10,30
10,20,10
10,30,5
10,40,30
20,10,4
20,20,30
20,30,40
20,40,20
"""
s = StringIO(txt)
sample_data = np.genfromtxt(s, delimiter=",", names=["x", "y","z"])
sample_data["z"].ndim
```

```
1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [232]: txt = """10,10,30
     ...: 10,20,10
     ...: 10,30,5
     ...: 10,40,30
     ...: 20,10,4
     ...: 20,20,30
     ...: 20,30,40
     ...: 20,40,20"""
In [233]: sample_data = np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(), delimiter=",", names=["x", "y","z"])
In [234]: sample_data
Out[234]: 
array([(10., 10., 30.), (10., 20., 10.), (10., 30.,  5.), (10., 40., 30.),
       (20., 10.,  4.), (20., 20., 30.), (20., 30., 40.), (20., 40., 20.)],
      dtype=[('x', '<f8'), ('y', '<f8'), ('z', '<f8')])
```

This is a 1d structured array.  Your unpacking produces:

```
In [235]: x, y, z = zip(*sample_data)
In [236]: x
Out[236]: (10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0)
In [237]: y
Out[237]: (10.0, 20.0, 30.0, 40.0, 10.0, 20.0, 30.0, 40.0)
In [238]: z
Out[238]: (30.0, 10.0, 5.0, 30.0, 4.0, 30.0, 40.0, 20.0)
```

Using field name indexing:

```
In [239]: sample_data['x']
Out[239]: array([10., 10., 10., 10., 20., 20., 20., 20.])
```

Your `x`, `y`, etc are tuples, not numpy arrays.  Often though `numpy/matplotlib` functions try to convert inputs to arrays:

```
In [240]: np.array(x)
Out[240]: array([10., 10., 10., 10., 20., 20., 20., 20.])
```

The `Z.ndim` means that `Z` is expected to be a numpy array, not a tuple.  We need to see the traceback to determine exactly what is this `Z`.

The full error:

```
In [242]: ax.plot_wireframe(x,y,z, color='green')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-242-cc87df9bd205>", line 1, in <module>
    ax.plot_wireframe(x,y,z, color='green')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/axes3d.py", line 1793, in plot_wireframe
    if Z.ndim != 2:
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'ndim'
```

Replacing the tuples with arrays gets past this error - by just a bit:

```
In [244]: ax.plot_wireframe(sample_data['x'],sample_data['y'],sample_data['z'],
     ...: color='green')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-244-319d7d15926d>", line 1, in <module>
    ax.plot_wireframe(sample_data['x'],sample_data['y'],sample_data['z'], color='green')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/axes3d.py", line 1794, in plot_wireframe
    raise ValueError("Argument Z must be 2-dimensional.")
ValueError: Argument Z must be 2-dimensional.
```

The first few lines of the `plot_wireframe` function:

```
    if Z.ndim != 2:
        raise ValueError("Argument Z must be 2-dimensional.")
    # FIXME: Support masked arrays
    X, Y, Z = np.broadcast_arrays(X, Y, Z)
    rows, cols = Z.shape
```

Which matches with the docs:

```
    Parameters
    ----------
    X, Y, Z : 2d arrays
        Data values.
```